# ERROR: Encoding not recognized: 'undefined' when trying to Sequelize Mysql

Tags: jquery, mysql, node.js, ubuntu, sequelize.js

I'm trying to install and run [Blocktogether](https://github.com/jdbillingham/blocktogether) on my Ubuntu server.

When I run  `./node_modules/.bin/sequelize --config=config/sequelize.json db:migrate --env=production`

I get this error:

> Sequelize CLI [Node: 12.22.9, CLI: 5.5.1, ORM: 5.22.5]
>
> Loaded configuration file "config/sequelize.json".
>
> Using environment "production".
>
> == 20160117144545-init: migrating =======
>
> query: /*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */
>
> query:
>
> /*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */
>
> query:
>
> /*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */
>
> query:
>
> /*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */
>
> query:
>
> /*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */

****ERROR: Encoding not recognized: 'undefined' (searched as: 'undefined')****

> at Object.getCodec
> (/etc/blocktogether/node_modules/mysql2/node_modules/iconv-lite/lib/index.js:106:23)
>
> at Object.getEncoder
> (/etc/blocktogether/node_modules/mysql2/node_modules/iconv-lite/lib/index.js:117:23)
>
> at Object.exports.encode (/etc/blocktogether/node_modules/mysql2/lib/parsers/string.js:23:25)    at Query.toPacket (/etc/blocktogether/node_modules/mysql2/lib/packets/query.js:16:30)
>
> at Query.start (/etc/blocktogether/node_modules/mysql2/lib/commands/query.js:55:38)
>
> at Query.execute (/etc/blocktogether/node_modules/mysql2/lib/commands/command.js:39:22)
>
> at Connection.handlePacket (/etc/blocktogether/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:408:32)
>
> at Connection.addCommand (/etc/blocktogether/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:430:12)
>
> at Connection.query (/etc/blocktogether/node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:493:17)
>
> at /etc/blocktogether/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/query.js:60:20
>
> at Promise._execute (/etc/blocktogether/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/debuggability.js:384:9)
>
> at Promise._resolveFromExecutor (/etc/blocktogether/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:518:18)
>
> at new Promise (/etc/blocktogether/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:103:10)
>
> at Query.run (/etc/blocktogether/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/query.js:39:12)
>
> at /etc/blocktogether/node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js:655:29
>
> at tryCatcher (/etc/blocktogether/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
>
> at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/etc/blocktogether/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:547:31)
>
> at Promise._settlePromise (/etc/blocktogether/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:604:18)
>
> at Promise._settlePromise0 (/etc/blocktogether/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:649:10)
>
> at Promise._settlePromises (/etc/blocktogether/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:729:18)
>
> at _drainQueueStep (/etc/blocktogether/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:93:12)
>
> at _drainQueue (/etc/blocktogether/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js:86:9)

My sequelize.json contains these lines:

```
{
   "development": {
     "username": "root",
     "password": "Password",
     "database": "Twitter",
     "host": "127.0.0.1",
     "dialect": "mysql"
   },
   "production": {
     "username": "root",
     "password": "Password",
     "database": "Twitter",
     "host": "127.0.0.1",
     "dialect": "mysql"
 
   }
 }
```

Would you please help me with this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this solved by removing all lines starting with /*!40.. in my sql files.

Answer (score 0):

utf8 as an alias to utf8mb3 was removed

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-unicode-utf8.html

In SQL file on top there was

```
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;
```

Removed `/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;` and it started working